# Esconder descrição com ''Display: none " é ruim pro SEO?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, seo

Tenho alguns *links* no site e vou adicionar uma descrição para cada um deles, e esconder a descrição, mas tenho duvida se esconder com `display: none` é ruim pro SEO.

Veja como pretendo fazer

```
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/descritivo.BR" <?=$nofollow?> target="_blank"><i class="sociais-sprits ico_top_face"></i> <p class="txtDescritivo"> Facebook </p></a></li>
```

Outra dúvida é sobre essa descrição dentro da âncora e da `LI`, através do parágrafo se é uma boa prática para o SEO.

Answer (score 3):

Dependerá muito do que você está ocultando!

Utilizar o `display:none;` para melhorar a interface e a experiência do usuário não vai te gerar penalidades no SEO.

Porém, se fizer algo para burlar os sistemas de buscas, mais cedo ou mais tarde poderá ser punido com multas de posicionamento nos serviços de busca.

Leia mais sobre:

- [**Texto e links ocultos**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66353)
- [**Técnicas de cloaking**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355)

Answer (score 2):

De uma maneira geral não. Pelo menos o Google é capaz de "enxergar" esse conteúdo. Ele não penaliza o *ranking* porque está marcado desta forma. Então dá para fazer o que precisa sem grandes preocupações.

É claro que não posso garantir que em qualquer situação ocorrerá isso. Pode haver algum padrão mais complexo onde esse mecanismo é usado que pode haver algum problema. Mas deve ser raro, até porque o mecani8smo isoladamente não vai causar nenhum problema.

O exemplo da pergunta não indica claramente como é feito, mas não parece que haverá problemas.

Não vejo problemas em mais nada a não ser que `<i class="sociais-sprits ico_top_face"></i>` não está sendo usado para nada.

Obviamente que o Google pode interpretar isso como tentativa de ocultar texto para facilitar a busca e punir. Mas isso não costuma ocorrer segundo o que li em fóruns da própria Google. Há um incentivo em fazer isso. De uma maneira geral não será considerado uma tentativa de burlar o mecanismo de busca.

É mais complicado dizer sobre outros mecanismos, mas duvido que difira muito disto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

O uso do `display:none` não afetará o seu SEO. No caso do `visibility:hidden`, poderá não ser indexado.